# Does the iPad 3 Retina displays the image @2x as if in iPhone Retina Display

Tags: ipad, retina-display, ios5.1

Does the iPad3 directly takes the images with the resolution of it by adding @2x at the image version as the iPhone/iPod Retina Display ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it does exactly as for the iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

For a example in icon image of normal display of have 57X57 size but retina display is 114X114
so we can use icon.png for 57X57(normal display) and icon@2X.png(retina display) for 114X114. compiler will take which one is adopt for itself.